# Transform XML to HTML in XSLT with string length condition

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tei

I have a XML file using TEI build like that:

```
<div type="chapter" n="1">
        <p>
          <s xml:id="e_1">sentence e1.</s>
          <s xml:id="f_1">sentence f1</s>
        </p>
        <p>
            <s xml:id="e_2"> sentence e2</s>
            <s xml:id="f_2"> sentence f2</s>
        </p>
</div>

<div type="chapter" n="2">
        <!-- -->
</div>
```

I need to transform it to this HTML structure:

```
<div>
<h1>Chapter 1</h1>
<div class="book-content">
 <p>
    <span class='source-language-sent' data-source-id='1'>sentence e1.</span>
    <span id='1' style='display:none'>sentence f1</span>
 </p>
 <p>
    <span class='source-language-sent' data-source-id='2'>sentence e2</span>
    <span id='2' style='display:none'>sentence f2</span>
 </p>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<h1>Chapter 2</h1>
<div class="book-content">
  <!-- -->
</div>
</div>
```

for now I use this XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="tei:body">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="tei:teiHeader">
      <xsl:comment>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </xsl:comment>
   </xsl:template>

   <!--create chapter-->
   <xsl:template match="tei:div">
      <xsl:element name="div">
         <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
               <xsl:text>book-content</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="h1">
               <xsl:text>Chapter</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="@n" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- create p-->
   <xsl:template match="tei:p">
      <xsl:element name="p">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- create s-->
   <xsl:template match="tei:s">
      <xsl:variable name="xmlid" select="@xml:id" />
      <xsl:if test="starts-with($xmlid, 'e')">
         <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
               <xsl:text>source-language-sent</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="data-source-id">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring($xmlid, 3, 4)" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="starts-with($xmlid, 'f')">
         <xsl:element name="span">
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
               <xsl:text>display:none</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
               <xsl:value-of select="substring($xmlid, 3, 4)" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My problem is that I need to create a new `<div class="book-content">` foreach 900 characters. But I don't want to cut my `s` elements so I need to calculate how many `s`element do I have to include in one `<div class="book-content">`to have somethings like 900 characters.

Comment: I don't see `<div class="book-chapter">` in your XSLT: Do you mean to build multiple  `<div class="book-chapter">` within `<div class="book-content">`? Or do you want to count those 900 characters over multiple `<div type="chapter">` of the TEI input? Is it crucial to keep those `<s>`-pairs together? And finally: what's happening when a single `<s>` exceeds 900 chars? - I think, I bit more information of what you like to achieve is helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake it is `<div class="book-content"`. I need to truncate each chapter with multiple `<div class="book-content"` according to the `<s>` tag naturally. There is no `<s>` with more 900 chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, but your example has too much of other things going on. I prefer to solve this in isolation, using my own example.

Consider the following input:

**XML**

```
<book>
    <chapter id="A">
        <para>
            <sentence id="1" length="23">Mary had a little lamb,</sentence>
            <sentence id="2" length="29">His fleece was white as snow,</sentence>
            <sentence id="3" length="30">And everywhere that Mary went,</sentence>
        </para>
        <para>
            <sentence id="4" length="24">The lamb was sure to go.</sentence>
            <sentence id="5" length="34">He followed her to school one day,</sentence>
        </para>
        <para>
            <sentence id="6" length="27">Which was against the rule,</sentence>
            <sentence id="7" length="35">It made the children laugh and play</sentence>
            <sentence id="8" length="24">To see a lamb at school.</sentence>
        </para>
        <para>
            <sentence id="9" length="34">And so the teacher turned it out, </sentence>
            <sentence id="10" length="27">But still it lingered near.</sentence>
        </para>
    </chapter>
    <chapter id="B">
        <para>
            <sentence id="11" length="35">Summertime, and the livin' is easy.</sentence>
            <sentence id="12" length="40">Fish are jumpin' and the cotton is high.</sentence>
            <sentence id="13" length="52">Oh, Your daddy's rich and your mamma's good lookin'.</sentence>
            <sentence id="14" length="35">So hush little baby, don't you cry.</sentence>
            <sentence id="15" length="54">One of these mornings you're going to rise up singing.</sentence>
        </para>
        <para>
            <sentence id="16" length="57">Then you'll spread your wings and you'll take to the sky.</sentence>
            <sentence id="17" length="35">So hush little baby, don't you cry.</sentence>
        </para>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

***Note***: the `length` values are given for illustration only; we will not be using them in the solution.

Our task is to split each chapter whose total length exceeds 200 characters into several chapters, by moving *whole* sentences only, while preserving the original para boundaries between groups of sentences.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl set">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:call-template name="split-chapter">
        <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="para/sentence"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="split-chapter">
    <xsl:param name="nodes"/>
    <xsl:param name="limit" select="200"/>
    <xsl:param name="remaining-nodes" select="dummy-node"/>
    <!-- 1. Calculate the total length of nodes -->
    <xsl:variable name="lengths">
        <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
            <length>
                <xsl:value-of select="string-length()" />
            </length>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="total-length" select="sum(exsl:node-set($lengths)/length)" />
    <!-- 2. Process the chapter: -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- If chapter is too long and can be shortened ... -->
        <xsl:when test="$total-length > $limit and count($nodes) > 1">
            <!-- ... try again with one node less. -->
            <xsl:call-template name="split-chapter">
                <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$nodes[not(position()=last())]"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="remaining-nodes" select="$remaining-nodes | $nodes[last()]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Otherwise create a chapter with the current nodes ... -->
            <chapter id="{@id}" length="{$total-length}" >
                <!-- ... list the paras participating in this chapter ... -->
                <xsl:for-each select="$nodes/parent::para">
                    <para>
                        <!-- ... and process the nodes still left in each para. -->
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="set:intersection(sentence, $nodes)"/>
                    </para>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </chapter>
            <!-- Then process any remaining nodes. -->
            <xsl:if test="$remaining-nodes">
                <xsl:call-template name="split-chapter">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodes" select="$remaining-nodes"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book>
   <chapter id="A" length="167">
      <para>
         <sentence id="1" length="23">Mary had a little lamb,</sentence>
         <sentence id="2" length="29">His fleece was white as snow,</sentence>
         <sentence id="3" length="30">And everywhere that Mary went,</sentence>
      </para>
      <para>
         <sentence id="4" length="24">The lamb was sure to go.</sentence>
         <sentence id="5" length="34">He followed her to school one day,</sentence>
      </para>
      <para>
         <sentence id="6" length="27">Which was against the rule,</sentence>
      </para>
   </chapter>
   <chapter id="A" length="120">
      <para>
         <sentence id="7" length="35">It made the children laugh and play</sentence>
         <sentence id="8" length="24">To see a lamb at school.</sentence>
      </para>
      <para>
         <sentence id="9" length="34">And so the teacher turned it out, </sentence>
         <sentence id="10" length="27">But still it lingered near.</sentence>
      </para>
   </chapter>
   <chapter id="B" length="162">
      <para>
         <sentence id="11" length="35">Summertime, and the livin' is easy.</sentence>
         <sentence id="12" length="40">Fish are jumpin' and the cotton is high.</sentence>
         <sentence id="13" length="52">Oh, Your daddy's rich and your mamma's good lookin'.</sentence>
         <sentence id="14" length="35">So hush little baby, don't you cry.</sentence>
      </para>
   </chapter>
   <chapter id="B" length="146">
      <para>
         <sentence id="15" length="54">One of these mornings you're going to rise up singing.</sentence>
      </para>
      <para>
         <sentence id="16" length="57">Then you'll spread your wings and you'll take to the sky.</sentence>
         <sentence id="17" length="35">So hush little baby, don't you cry.</sentence>
      </para>
   </chapter>
</book>
```

Comment: thanks for your example. In my xml file, I have `<s>` elements in `<p>` so it seems to be a litte bit more difficult.

Comment: @ChesterMcAllister I don't think it makes a very big difference, but in case the required adjustment isn't obvious, I have changed my example to better fit yours.